# Very Slow Upload Times to GCP Apt Artifact registry

Tags: google-artifact-registry

I have a CI/CD system uploading numerous large deb's into a Google Cloud Artifact Registry for Apt packages. The normal upload time is roughly 10 seconds for the average package. Yesterday all of the upload commands to this artifact registry started to hang until they are either terminated by an external trigger or timeout (over 30 minutes).
Any attempt to delete packages from the registry timeout without deleting the package.
The command I have been using to upload is:

```
gcloud artifacts apt upload ${ARTIFACT_REPOSITORY} --location=${ARTIFACT_LOCATION} --project ${ARTIFACT_PROJECT} --source=${debPackageName} --verbosity=debug
```

I started by updating all Gcloud versions to the latest version

```
Google Cloud SDK 409.0.0
alpha 2022.11.04
beta 2022.11.04
bq 2.0.81
bundled-python3-unix 3.9.12
core 2022.11.04
gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0
gsutil 5.16
```

I try to delete packages thinking perhaps the artifact registry was getting bloated using this command:

```
gcloud artifacts packages delete --location={LOCATION} --project {PROJECT} --repository={REPOSITORY} {PACKAGE} --verbosity=debug
```

But I consistently get:

```
 "message": "Deadline expired before operation could complete."
```

The debug output from the original command and the delete command both spam this kind of message:

```
DEBUG: https://artifactregistry.googleapis.com:443 "GET /v1/projects/{PROJECT}/locations/{LOCATION}/operations/f9885192-e1aa-4273-9b61-7b0cacdd5023?alt=json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

- When I created a new repository I was able to upload to it without the timeout issues.

Comment: +1, we have been experiencing same troubles for several days. First such fail happened for us at 10 Nov ~16:00 UTC. Upgrading gcloud, using official `google/cloud-sdk` docker didn't help. Debugging step-by-step shows that some of requests just hang forever even for our 3Mb package. Network activity shows short spike and then almost zero.

Comment: Getting the same problem, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the lead for Artifact Registry.  Firstly apologies that you're seeing this kind of latency with update operations to Apt Repositories.  They are likely caused by regenerating the index for the repo. The bigger the repo gets, the longer this takes.

If you do a bunch of individual uploads/deletes, this causes the index generation to queue up, and you're getting timeouts.  We did change some of the locking behavior around this recently, so we may have inadvertently swapped one performance issue with another.

We are planning to stop doing the index generation in the same transaction as the file modification.  Instead we'll generate it asynchronously, and will look at batching or de-duping so that less work is done for a large number of individual updates.   It will mean that the index isn't up-to-date the moment the upload call finishes, but will be eventually consistent.

We're working on this now as a priority but you may not see changes in performance for a few weeks. The only real workaround is to do less frequent updates or to keep the repositories smaller.

Apologies again, we definitely want to get this working in a performant way.

Comment: We've tried to make our repository smaller, but we can't delete any package due to same timeout issue. Moving to new repo is not very convenient for us, are there any other ways to deal with this issue now?